# int value cast to float and then passed to Math.round

Tags: java, findbugs

I have a method which creates a file size String for displaying to the user. FindBugs is saying that an **int is cast into a float and then passed to Math.round**.

```
 public static String createFileSizeString(long size)
 {
    if (size < 1024)
    {
       return size + " bytes";
    }
    else if (size < 1048576)
    {
       return (Math.round(((size * 10) / 1024)) / 10) + " KB";
    }
    else
    {
       return (Math.round(((size * 10) / 1048576)) / 10) + " MB";
    }
 }
```

FindBugs goes on to say: "This operation should always be a no-op, since the converting an integer to a float should give a number with no fractional part. It is likely that the operation that generated the value to be passed to Math.round was intended to be performed using floating point arithmetic."

How is it a no-op? Should I add an explicit cast to `(size * 10) / 1024` so that `((float)size * 10) / 1024` appears instead?

Answer (score 3):

The code

```
((size * 10) / 1024)
```

is a whole number and if you round a whole you should get the same number every time.

Perhaps what you intended was to round down

```
return size * 10 / 1024 / 10.0 + " KB";
```

or to round half up.

```
return (size * 10 + 512) / 1024 / 10.0 + " KB";
```

or almost the same thing using Math.round

```
return Math.round(size / 102.4) / 10.0 + " KB";
```

This will give you the number KB with one decimal place.